# Can't build Cython/distutils in OS X Lion.

Tags: python, gcc, osx-lion, distutils, cython

I have looked everywhere on the internet for a solution but haven't found anything helpful.

I am trying to use Cython to embed C code into my python programs.

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

When I run the above it complains about the compiler, not being gcc-4.0. I now know that only gcc-4.2 is installed on Lion (python 2.7 32 bit). Is there anyway of getting 4.0, I tried fink but it doesn't have it. (I have run this on windows and my friends laptop with snow leopard and it runs fine).

If I try specifying the installed gcc I get

```
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'posix' with 'gcc' compiler
```

To check the possible compilers I ran:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --help-compiler
```

and got these:

```
List of available compilers:
  --compiler=bcpp     Borland C++ Compiler
  --compiler=cygwin   Cygwin port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
  --compiler=emx      EMX port of GNU C Compiler for OS/2
  --compiler=mingw32  Mingw32 port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
  --compiler=msvc     Microsoft Visual C++
  --compiler=unix     standard UNIX-style compiler
```

As far as I can see I can't install any of these either.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have the Developer Tools/XCode installed?

Comment: Yeah installed xcode but it only comes with gcc-4.2. I think the old gcc-4.0 may have been ppc (?)

Comment: Can you add the error message that you get?  It seems weird that it would specify the exact version necessary and not just a minimum version.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem while compiling greenlet in virtualenv, solved by manually setting desired compiler in file `lib/python2.7/config/Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using an older 32-bit-only Python perhaps installed from python.org.  Try upgrading to a 64-/32-bit Python 2.7.2 [here](http://www.python.org/download/) or simply use the Apple-supplied Python 2.7.1  in Lion (`/usr/bin/python2.7`).

Answer (score 0):

If I try specifying the installed gcc I get

How did you specify it?  Using the environment variable CC?

error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'posix' with 'gcc' compiler

Makes me think you passed `--compiler=gcc`, but as you see in the `--help-compiler` message it’s not a valid value.