# Why do I get unrecognized command line error when building C extension with distutils

Tags: python, compiler-construction, distutils, setup.py

I am trying to build a source using `python`'s `distutils`. I have created a simple `setup.py` following an [example](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html), and building it as suggested works fine:

```
python setup.py build
```

Now it is possible to build a source with a desired compiler; a list of compilers [can be found as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453773/cant-build-cython-distutils-in-os-x-lion)

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --help-compiler
List of available compilers:
  --compiler=bcpp     Borland C++ Compiler
  --compiler=cygwin   Cygwin port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
  --compiler=emx      EMX port of GNU C Compiler for OS/2
  --compiler=mingw32  Mingw32 port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
  --compiler=msvc     Microsoft Visual C++
  --compiler=unix     standard UNIX-style compiler
```

However, if I try to use, for example, the `mingw32` compiler as follows

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

I get the following error output:

```
building 'demo' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7
gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -DMAJOR_VERSION=1 -DMINOR_VERSION=0 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c demo.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/demo.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-cygwin’
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mdll’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What is the cause for this problem? Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to specify something else? Am I using wrong versions (Ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7.3, Distutils 1.0a4)?Do I need to 'remove' the offending options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really have MinGW on Ubuntu.

As you already quote,

```
--compiler=mingw32  Mingw32 port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
```

You should try `--compiler=unix` instead.

Comment: Ah I see. I just installed `mingw32` by running `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw32`, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

could you try installing python development headers and then run your command .

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: I don't think this has any effect on the used compiler options and/or the compiler's understanding of them.